# Bash to append domain in search field of resolv.conf after vpnc connection in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vpn, resolve

After vpn connection,I am not able to resolve any machines in remote gateway.It looks like remote domain is added to domain field instead of adding it to the Search field in /etc/resolv.conf

I want the remote domain to add to search field along with local domain.Can anyone tell a bash or script to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a bash script with this content: echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf  and put it in /etc/network/if-up-d/ and chmod script with 755